# Yii custom url routing

Tags: .htaccess, url, yii, seo, routes

I want to create friendly urls in Yii framework.

An example:

```
mysitename.com/country/city/travelling-type
```

or

```
mysitename.com/country/city/travelling-type/price
mysitename.com/city/price
```

etc.

The problem is that it confuses the parameters.
So I tried to solve it with below code, but it is not good enough:

```
'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'appendParams' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'useStrictParsing' => FALSE,
        'rules' => array(
            '<country:\w+>/<city:\w+>/<travelling_type:\w+>/<accommodation:\w+>/<caftering:\w+>/<price_from:\d+/<price_to:\d+>' => 'Travels/list'
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: The problem with your approach is that you have params determined only by position, so it is not really possible to determine which params is which. You could use named params instead.

Answer (score 2):

Its not really easy to do that since Yii doesn't know the difference between those two URLs:

```
mysitename.com/{city}/{price}
mysitename.com/{city}/{accommodation}
```

What you can do though is change the route to this system:

```
'<param1:\w+>/<param2:\w+>/<param3:\w+>/<param4:\w+>/<param5:\w+>/<param6:\d+/<param7:\d+>' => 'Travels/list'
```

Your action would have to identify which query parameter represents which parameter for your search query. In some instances in your system, this should be easy enough. For example, there's a limited number of countries, there's probably a limited number of traveling types, etc.

i.e.

In case of

```
mysitename.com/{city}/{accommodation}
```

your system would query "param1" (= city) against a list of countries, cities, traveling types, accomodation types and catering types to determine that param1 is indeed a city. It would then proceed with param2 to determine that it defines the accomodation.

Prices are easier to identify because they are different data types (in case of a traveling search engine integer is probably good enough), so you can easily identify prices by simply checking if a price is an integer (or similar).
To differentiate price_from and price_to I suggest you assume that if there's only one price, it's price_from; if there's two prices, the first is price_from, the second is price_to.
If you want to only set price_to, you set price_from to 0.

I hope that covers what you want to do. It can be quite complicated to set up, but that's the price you have to pay for a URL route like that. :)